# Sql Unique Entry Issue

Tags: sql

In my db I have a list of entries. Each one of the entries will have a corresponding year attached to it. I want to do a query where I can check all the entries within the database and the query will return the all the different years contained in the database. Example if I have 4 entries (Years: 1998, 1999, 2000, 2001) and each entry has a different year. The statement should return all four years used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT yearfield FROM tablename;
```

Answer (score 1):

It's *very* hard to answer questions like this without schema specifically, but you'd want something like this, depending on your SQL variant:

```
SELECT distinct year FROM tablename;
```

Also note it's not really an "issue" unless you've actually had some trouble after trying...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're requesting right, you're looking for "Distinct".

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

So, in your case you might have a query like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT year FROM table;
```